# Tracking top N value on stream of data

Tags: python

I want to track top N largest value givens a stream of incoming data points (potentially very large). N is a relatively small number, let's say in the neighborhood of 10s, not hundreds or more. Is the following code efficient or there are better ways of doing that?

```
import heapq
n = 10
topn = []
def push(item):
    global topn
    if len(topn) >= n:
        heapq.heappushpop(topn, item)
    else:
        heapq.push(topn, item)
```

Comment: Looks pretty good to me, however if you have specific speed requirements you may want to benchmark.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to pass in an iterable and use `heapq.nlargest`?

Comment: that's what stream of data means - it comes in one by one.

Answer (score 0):

`heapq.nlargest()` is implemented like this:

```
def nlargest(n, iterable):
    """Find the n largest elements in a dataset.

    Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, reverse=True)[:n]
    """
    if n < 0:
        return []
    it = iter(iterable)

    result = list(islice(it, n))
    if not result:
        return result
    heapify(result)

    _heappushpop = heappushpop
    for elem in it:
        _heappushpop(result, elem)
    result.sort(reverse=True)

    return result
```